# connecting windows and linux machine using putty

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, putty

Sometimes i need to use the office computer at home.So I have installed putty in my home computer and get connected to the office system.If i download and install something in my office computer which internet connection will it take to download.I have a doubt will it use the internet connection at home.can anyone please clarify my doubt

Answer (score 1):

Putty is simply an SSH client. You are making a remote connection to your office machine. So when you use putty, you are essentially logged into the office machine and will be using it as though physically accessing the terminal in the office itself. So any downloads you do will be made using the office connection.

However, if any of this data needs to be transferred to your home machine, this will use the internet connection at home.

Answer (score 0):

Putty creates a tunnel to your machine.  Any commands you run on it run locally on THAT machine, as if you were sitting there using the terminal.  So, if you unzip something, or run and install package, it will run on the machine it's executed on.

In other words, if you are sitting at your Windows machine, and open a Putty session to your Linux box, you are no longer talking to your local system.  Everything done within that window is executed on the Linux box.

This also means that if you download a 4GB DVD ISO file, your home internet connection won't know anything about it, other than the text that the transmission is taking place.  All the physical data will run locally on the remote network.

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, it is also possible download on both machines when the SSH tunneling is enabled within current session. Which is also possible in particular with `Putty`.

[image]

As an exmaple, you can work on internet from your local browser, but the remote machine will be doing this for you instead your local machine, resending all the data to/from local machine. It is achieved having ssh tunnel with ports forwarded and settings in browser properly set, for instance 127.0.0.1:1080 in SOCKS proxy - listening on 127.0.0.1, port 1080. You can configure any application that can use a SOCKS proxy to use it.